# Why does my API key not load within the export function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get my APIkey to load within the Home function but although it loads outside it, it doesn't load within it.

```
import mapboxgl from '!mapbox-gl'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax

const {MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN} = process.env;
console.log(MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN) ## Works

export default function Home(MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN) {
  console.log({MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}) ## Doesn't work

  useEffect(() => {

    console.log({MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}) ## Doesn't work
  });

  return (
          <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container" />
  )
}
```

Comment: Because you shadow the variable with `Home(MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN)`. Remove it from the parameter list of `Home`.

Comment: @AndyRay Please post answers as such, not as a comment/question.

Comment: I don't personally think answers have a significant effect on questions like this except to give the answerer fake internet points. I prefer only to answer when it's a more involved question, or one that is likely to benefit others searching for the problem. If it can be answered in one line, a comment is easier and faster and still helps the asker.

Answer (score 0):

edit: In response to your comment `"still dones't work - I think it has something to do with env variables not being sent to the browser"`.

If it is loading correctly outside of that function, then you could also export it from this file and import it every other place that you need to use it. Like this...

```
// File: constants.ts
const {MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN} = process.env;

export default {
  MAPBOX_TOKEN: MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  MAPBOX_TOKEN_2: process.env.MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN, // you can also read it like this
}
```

Then import to the value:

```
import mapboxgl from '!mapbox-gl'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import CONSTANTS from 'constants';

export default function Home() {
  console.log(CONSTANTS.MAPBOX_TOKEN) ## Should work now

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(CONSTANTS.MAPBOX_TOKEN_2) ## Should work now
  });

  return (
          <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container" />
  )
}
```

---

---

---

(OLD ANSWER)
You are setting a parameter with the same name `MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN` to Home(). This is overriding the outer variable. You will need to pass the value to Home if you want to use it in the inner-scope OR you can remove the parameter.

i.e.

```
import mapboxgl from '!mapbox-gl'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax

const {MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN} = process.env;
console.log(MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN) ## Works

export default function Home() {
  console.log(MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN) ## Should work now

  useEffect(() => {

    console.log(MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN) ## Should work now
  });

  return (
          <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container" />
  )
}
```

Comment: still dones't work - I think it has something to do with env variables not being sent to the browser

Comment: @Reuben posted an update